# Spring Boot -Hibernate 5 simple application initializing in 3 minutes

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-entitymanager

I am using Spring boot with Hibernate to connect with Oracle database. The application works fine but when I run the application with Dddl.auto flag set to update it takes 3 minutes just to initialize the entity manager. here are my model classes and cfg.xml.

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hhhh.cpckubosallr.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1610:gghg</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">DEMO</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">ggggg#78GHTd</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<mapping class ="student.mappings.model.Student" />
<mapping class ="student.mappings.model.Vehicle" />
<mapping class ="student.mappings.model.Subject" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT", schema="JAVACODE")
public class Student 
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id")
private Vehicle vehicle;

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", vehicle=" + vehicle + ", subject=" + subject + "]";
}

public Vehicle getVehicle() 
{
return vehicle;
}

public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) 
{
this.vehicle = vehicle;
}

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="subject_id")
private List<Subject> subject;

public List<Subject> getSubject() 
{
return subject;
}

public void setSubject(List<Subject> subject) 
{
this.subject = subject;
}

public Student(Long id, String name, Vehicle vehicle, List<Subject> subject) 
{
super();
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.vehicle = vehicle;
this.subject = subject;
}

public Long getId() 
{
return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) 
{
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() 
{
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) 
{
this.name = name;
}

public Student()
{
super();
}

public Student(Long id, String name) 
{
super();
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
}

public Student(Long id, String name, Vehicle vehicle) {
super();
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.vehicle = vehicle;
}
}
```

Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("student.mappings")
@EntityScan("student.mappings")
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class StudentMappingsTemplateClient 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(StudentMappingsTemplateClient.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: um ... AWS databases arent meant to be initialized remotely; they are most likely hundreds, if not thousands of kilometers from your home machine on a crowded network ... having a very slow transaction rate is pretty much what one would expect. **Never** use AWS databases from your home machine, you will only achieve a decent transaction rate **within** the AWS network. Set up a development database on your machine and use that to experiment. Deploy your DDL to AWS once you're **finished** with your database design. Also : have a look at the price tables, remote transactions cost money

Comment: come to think of it : you probably should'nt do your homework on AWS, thats like trying to catch bugs with thermonuclear missiles. Use H2 embedded databases, stay local and keep enterprise networks out of the classroom.

Comment: But It initializes in 3 seconds when I set the DDL-update flag to create or none.
and I am also using the same Database for my production environment applications they work fine with the flag set to update.

Comment: DDL update requires **many transactions** or statement executions to and from the AWS network - the rate between networks is very low. If you stay within the same network it will be much higher, thats why your _"production environment"_ does not suffer from this. Also : who in his right mind uses DDL update for "production"? The answer is : noone because at some point you **will** lose data, possibly even most of the database _(depending on your model changes)_ - and this can cost you your job ... in the real world, that is

Comment: Updating a schema can be slow. It needs to obtain the schema, create a diff, execute that diff. Generally you shouldn't let hibernate manage your schema especially not in production like environments. Use something like Flyway or LiquiBase to manage your schema. Also you should ditch your `hibernate.cfg` and move the properties to the `applicaiton.properties`. Place your `StudentMappingsTemplateClient` in the `student.mappings` package and remove all annotations but `@SpringBootApplication` . You are basically working around Spring Boot with this configuration.

Comment: also : spring supports flyway and liquibase, its very possible to achieve fully automatic, controllable database migration at application restart with spring boot. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool